# How to remove remote fork changes from my git fork on my local machine

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I did the following with my `git` local fork to get a co-developer's changes on my fork. We both are pointing to the same `upstream`.

```
git remote add colleague_fork url/to/colleague_fork
git pull colleague_fork colleague_branch_to_test
```

**Now I am want to switch back to my own personal master & get rid of the changes that got into my local fork.** *How can I do that?*

Is it as simple as `git checkout master`? How does it work when I have multiple remote forks added like upstreams to my personal fork?

Comment: I don't see any point where you merged those branches together.  You didn't do that, did you?

Comment: @Makoto not sure what your question means but to clarify, we both were pointing to same upstream. I was on master & colleague's branch was forked from master.

Comment: @Makoto I updated my question to clarify better. Does the question make sense to you now ?